# Identifier expected in an ActionListener

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, actionlistener

I compiled my code and got the error:

```
C:\Users\RJ\Desktop>javac  windowTest.java
windowTest.java:17: error: <identifier> expected
        click.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
                               ^
windowTest.java:22: error: ';' expected
          });
           ^
2 errors
```

I am still very new to java and would appreciate examples and/or step by step help with explanations. If I move the override I get an error saying I didn't override. My code is:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class windowTest extends JFrame implements ActionListener{
public static void main(String args[]){
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    JLabel label = new JLabel("This is a test.");
        JButton click = new JButton("Test");
    JPanel buttonPan = new JPanel();
    JPanel textPan = new JPanel();
    final JTextField textIn = new JTextField();
    @Override
    click.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){      
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        String text = textIn.getText();
        System.out.println(text);
        }
      });
    buttonPan.setSize(100, 100);
    textIn.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(700, 48));
    textPan.add(textIn);
    buttonPan.add(click);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(800, 700);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        label.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
        label.setVerticalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
        frame.add(label, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    frame.add(buttonPan, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    frame.add(textPan, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setTitle("Window Test");
       }
    }
```

Comment: remove the `@Override` annotation. pro tip - use a IDE

Comment: @ug_: No, move the `@Override` annotation down. It should go just above the `actionPerformed` method.

Comment: I get an error saying windowTest is not abstract and ActionListener is not overridden.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Good point, and better fix.

Comment: @user3598176, See the second half of my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First problem, you need to move `@Override` down, because that is an annotation which applies to a method definition, which is inside the anonymous class.

```
click.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){      
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
    String text = textIn.getText();
    System.out.println(text);
    }
  });
```

Second problem, your `windowTest` class **claims that it** `implements ActionListener` but does not implement `actionPerformed`. Since you do not seem to need it, you can just remove that in the declaration.

```
public class windowTest extends JFrame{
...
}
```

With these two changes, your application will compile and run.

Comment: Glad you didn't recommend using `addActionListener(this)`. 1+